# can we prioritize test scenario in cucumber feature file during execution?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

Login.feature

Scenario: log in using valid credential

Scenario: log in using invalid credential

How can i execute second scenario first

Comment: This is a solution, but what is your problem? Why do you want to execute in a particular order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class TestRunner and configure the cucumberOptions to execute the features
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-run-tests-using-a-test-runner-file-for-cucumber

https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/

```
@CucumberOptions(tags = "@smoke and @fast")
public class RunCucumberTest {}
```